# How to pass array to modal?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Axios to get countries list from REST API so I setup modals each having a country name and flag.

On click of any country name, console will log the country.

I have a history modal that I want to pass the last 5 countries clicked to it.

```
<!-- History Modal -->
<div>
  <b-button v-b-modal.modal-1>View History</b-button>
  <b-modal id="modal-1" title="History">
    <p class="my-4">{{ country.name }}</p>
  </b-modal>
</div>
```

Here's the script for console logging

```
handleClick(country) {
  console.log("Clicked on: " + country.name);
},
```

[Full Script is here](https://pastebin.com/0t1N0UyF)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a circular buffer in `handleClick()` and pass in the country that was clicked into it. This will kept the last 5 countries clicked in the history array for you to access.

```
data(){
 return{
   index: 0,
   history: [],
 }
},
methods:{
  handleClick(data){
   console.log("Clicked on: " + data.name);
   this.history[this.index] = data;
   this.index = (this.index + 1) % 5;
  }
}
```

Comment: <p class="my-4">{{ this.history }}</p> isn't returning anything in the modal but the javascript is functional i think
@S.Ramjit

Comment: @AhmadTakkoush It should be ```<p class="my-4">{{ history }}</p>``` there's no need for `this` in the template

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I had a problem that it wasn't getting the countries turns out i had to add `this.fetchData();` at the end of my handleclick function.